# iOS 5 returns wrong user location while iOS 4 doesn't

Tags: ios5

I have 3 iPads:

iPad 3G/WiFi iOS 5.0.1

iPad 2 3G/WiFi iOS 4.3.5

iPad 2 WiFi iOS 5.0.1

Running the same code on all 3 iPads results in my location being reported as 'New York City' on the iPads running iOS 5.0.1 while the iPad running iOS 4.3.5 returns my correct location.

What might be the cause?

Thanks!

Code added:

```
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Created by Michael Superczynski on 8/27/11.
//  Copyright 2011 HyperNova Software. All rights reserved.

#import "Locator.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    Locator *locator;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Locator *locator;

@end

//  AppDelegate.m
//  Created by Michael Superczynski on 8/27/11.
//  Copyright 2011 HyperNova Software. All rights reserved.

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Locator.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize locator;
. . .

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   
    Locator *aLocator = [[Locator alloc]init];
    locator = aLocator;
CLLocationManager *aLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager = aLocationManager;
locationManager.delegate = locator;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
locationManager.purpose = @"This will show your location on the map";
[locator startStandardUpdates];
. . .
}

//
//  Locator.h
//
//  Created by Michael Superczynski on 8/30/11.
//  Copyright 2011 HyperNova Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Locator : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKReverseGeocoderDelegate>
{
    NSString *currentLocation;
    CLLocation *currentCLLocation;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentCLLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

-(void)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
-(void)startStandardUpdates;

@end

//
//  Locator.m
//
//  Created by Michael Superczynski on 8/30/11.
//  Copyright 2011 HyperNova Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Locator.h"

@implementation Locator

@synthesize currentLocation;
@synthesize currentCLLocation;
@synthesize locationManager;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)startStandardUpdates
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
    currentCLLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    float latitude;
    float longitude; 
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        latitude = kDefaultLocationLatitudeA;
        longitude = kDefaultLocationLongitudeA; 
    }
    else
    {
        latitude = (float)locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
        longitude = (float)locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    }
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    [self reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation:location];
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    currentCLLocation = newLocation;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
    newLocation.coordinate.longitude] argument:nil]; 
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power
    if ((abs((int)(howRecent))) < 30.0)
        [self reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation:newLocation];
}

-(void)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]initWithCoordinate:location.coordinate];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];    
}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark    
{
    self.currentLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", placemark.administrativeArea, placemark.country];
}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) 
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    float latitude = kDefaultLocationLatitudeA;
    float longitude = kDefaultLocationLongitudeA; 
    CLLocation *cLLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) 
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
@end
```